# Number sign before snippets in vs code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Snippets in visual code are not working as I expect them to do. When I type foreach, nothing happens. If I type #foreach, then I get the snippet, but the '#' sign remains, making the compiler think it's a preprocessor directive.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What language are you using in `vscode`?

Comment: C#, sorry I forgot to mention

Comment: Works fine for me. Type `fore` then `tab`.

Comment: Also works for me, using the main C# extension. Is this a user snippet, or do you have a different extension installed?

Comment: Interresting. Yea, I have the C# extension and the Unity tools extension.. It must be that one that breaks it.. I'll try some other stuff.